# How to check Kotlin BufferedReader use { return something } has called method close()?

Tags: kotlin

My sample Kotlin about `BufferedReader().use {}` 
I wonder if the `close()` is called when I return early in the `use` block

```
fun main() {
    sendGet()
}

fun sendGet() {
    val queryUrl = "http://www.google.com/search?q=kotlin&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8"
    val url = URL(queryUrl)
    val conn = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    conn.requestMethod = "GET"
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")

    val responseCode = conn.responseCode
    println("Response code: ${responseCode}")

    when (responseCode) {
        200 -> {
            println("response: ${conn.getResponseText()}")
        }
        else -> println("Bad response code: ${responseCode}")
    }

}

private fun HttpURLConnection.getResponseText(): String {
    BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use {
        return it.readText()
    }
}
```

Comment: `use` guarantees that `close` is called for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the source code for `use` in `stdlib` by navigating using "Go to implementation" (<kbd>Cmd + B</kbd> on a Mac):

```
public inline fun <T : Closeable?, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R {
    var exception: Throwable? = null
    try {
        return block(this)
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        exception = e
        throw e
    } finally {
        when {
            apiVersionIsAtLeast(1, 1, 0) -> this.closeFinally(exception)
            this == null -> {}
            exception == null -> close()
            else ->
                try {
                    close()
                } catch (closeException: Throwable) {
                    // cause.addSuppressed(closeException) // ignored here
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Because the call to `close` is inside the finally block, it will execute even on an early return.